# Question about 2 instances of package in pipfile

Tags: python, package, pipenv

Im going through exercises on https://www.practicepython.org/
In ex17 there is a task to install packages "request" and "BeautifulSoup"

I did it but since an error occured i installed "BeautifulSoup" and "BeautifulSoup4"

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
requests = "*"
beautifullsoup = "*"
beautifulsoup4 = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Will it couse any problems if i will import only beautifulsoup4?
Can I delete the beautifullsoup = "*" from file and it will be ok? 
How can i do it?
Should i write additional commands in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `pipenv uninstall beautifullsoup` to remove the installed package and you should be fine.